# validation false, although the data is filled

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, ckeditor, hosting

I have form validation like this :

```
function insert() {

    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '*column must be filled');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isi', 'Isi', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

      $this->layout->addJs('ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
      $this->layout->addJs('js/admin/b267648789c30a07b0efa5bce7bdd9fe.js');
      $this->layout->view('admin/admin_view/insertAdmin_view');
    } else {

      $data = array(
          'title' => $this->input->post('judul'),
          'content' => $this->input->post('isi'),
      );
      $this->db->insert('newses', $data);

       ... other proses ...
              }
  }
```

although I filled the data in form add data (I use ckeditor for adding data), condition always false so it's not adding data that I want. but it's got error 'if I add some html data, but if I add normal data text it's work well'. once again when I running my program in localhost xampp it's all work but when I use hosting that happen. 
any suggest ? 
thank you for all advice.

Comment: Are you getting the post value of the ckeditor value (text in the ckeditor)?

Comment: but I think that's not the problem, cause in localhost its work well. are in the host any other configuration for ckeditor ?

Comment: please mention that the code works in localhost and not on live server...check if you get the ckeditor value on live server.

Comment: that's code above works in localhost but not in server. if I add data only normal text like :
"<p> Hallo, or another</p>" 
it's work although in localhost or server ,but if I post some like :
"<tr><td><font='calibri' size='14'>like this</font></td></tr>". 
it's only works in localhost.

Comment: how should I do to check value ckeditor on server?

Comment: echo validation_errors();exit; do this to see if you have validation errors...

Answer (score 0):

Print the errors of validation

```
function insert() {

$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '*column must be filled');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('isi', 'Isi', 'required');
//echo validation_errors();
echo $this->input->post('judul')."<br>";
echo $this->input->post('isi');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

  $this->layout->addJs('ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
  $this->layout->addJs('js/admin/b267648789c30a07b0efa5bce7bdd9fe.js');
  $this->layout->view('admin/admin_view/insertAdmin_view');
} else {

  $data = array(
      'title' => $this->input->post('judul'),
      'content' => $this->input->post('isi'),
  );
  $this->db->insert('newses', $data);

   ... other proses ...
          }
   }
```

Comment: not work, I got 'Denied access to web pages' . if you put 'exit;' after 'echo validation_error();' it's mean you stop program until there so the page wont get load, isn't it?

Comment: exit only means you want to stop at this point or check execution till that point...

Comment: try without exit...it will print errors at the top..let me know